# How to protect/unprotect macro toggle

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a very simple macro created to toggle hiding and unhiding rows. I'm very new to VBA so apologies for the basic question.  The code for the toggle is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Rows("57:73").Hidden = Not Rows("57:73").Hidden
End Sub
```

When protecting the sheet, the macro obviously doesn't function, so I'm trying to use the code below to lock/unlock the sheet within the function but am getting a 424 error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Final).Unprotect (1234)
    Rows("57:73").Hidden = Not Rows("57:73").Hidden
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Final).Protect (1234)
End Sub
```

The workbook is titled QN6 and the sheet is titled Final. Any help to fix the code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If rows `Rows("57:73")` are on the sheet named `"Final"`, you need to use quotes for all strings

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final")
        .Unprotect "1234"
        .Rows("57:73").Hidden = Not .Rows("57:73").Hidden
        .Protect "1234"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

.

Another option is to protect the sheet once, using **`Protect`** parameter `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

This sub in **`ThisWorkbook`** Module:

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 'in ThisWorkbook Module

    'Set UserInterfaceOnly to True to protect the user interface, but not macros

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Protect Password:="1234", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

and then you don't need to `Unprotect` / `Protect` the sheet for every action in your Subs

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final")
        .Rows("57:73").Hidden = Not .Rows("57:73").Hidden
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I’m glad it helped!